# add mesh in object mode menu comes passive

Tags: modeling, object-mode

In the object mode when I add a new object add menu generally get passive first (not pressing f9) , in edit mode no problem , this problem in only get in object mode
[image]

Comment: Blender remembers what you did last. Next time you add a mesh, minimize the popup and then from now on it should be minimized when you add a new mesh.

Comment: thanks for your answer but my problem is getting popup passive so I can't change anything (segments , radius etc.) on popup. how can I fix this? Thanks again.

Comment: Hmm weird, Can you [share](https://blend-exchange.com/) your .blend file?